# Android compose - modular app design - how to manage theming?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, modularization

I'm working on modularizing a test application with Android Compose and have the application stuff woking well, however it seems that if you want to add custom theming like colors and fonts you run into problems.

So as example under the app/src/main/java/com/xx/myapp/theme/ we extend Color.kt

```
val Green900 = Color(0XFF242d2d)
val Green800 = Color(0XFF354242)

val Colors.green800: Color
    @Composable
    get() = Green800

val Colors.green700: Color
    @Composable
    get() = Green700
```

Now trying to use these in any of the "Modules" is not possible and the only way I can see is to duplicate the whole theme structure in each module which seems stupid?

So if I have a module in the structure as example components/src/main/java/com/xx/components/BottomNavBar.kt I cannot use

```
selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.gray800,
```

unless I duplicate the Color.kt inside this module OR I include the "app" module inside the build.gradle.kts for this module...

```
 "implementation"(project(Modules.app))
```

which will cause a "Circular dependency" if I'm not mistaken

Any suggestions on how to manage this without duplication?

Thanks
J

Comment: Could you show build.gradle file? I want to how you included modules. Look like you included the app module in feature modules.

Comment: If you leave the theme components in the default "app module" and have other modules you will run into a circular dependency issue sooner or later. So best is to keep the theme elements outside of the default app module in a complex app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood one way to do it is to have a module only for the shared definitions in such a way that you do not need to import the entire app module. This shared module will of course be imported by the app module as well.

More in general everytime you have a circular dependency you need to check whether the solution can be to split the modules in smaller ones in such a way that you break the circle.

Comment: Yes thanks - worked out the only/best/practical way to make it work was to extract the "theme" components from the app module and added them to the "components" module I already have that is a dependency in all the other modules so it's working great now!

Answer (score -1):

In your ui.theme folder that includes **Color.kt, Shape.kt, Theme.kt** and **Type.kt** you will need to define your colors in **Color.kt**

```
val Green900 = Color(0XFF242d2d)
val Green800 = Color(0XFF354242)
```

In your **Theme.kt** you define your general Theme for the whole App that my look like this:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = LightColorPalette,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

And also:

```
val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Green900,
    primaryVariant = Green800,
    secondary = Green200

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color.White,
    surface = Color.White,
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.Black,
    onBackground = Color.Black,
    onSurface = Color.Black,
    */
)
```

As you can see you can define all of your desired surfaces, backgrounds etc with a color that you defined and later use it like this:

```
MaterialTheme.colors.primary
```

You can also have a look [here on the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material)